# Designing C-meter, 8-9 precise digits

Tags: capacitor, measurement

I am thinking how it is possible to build C-meter which would have show some 8-9 digits (absolute accuracy is not that strict, only relative accuracy matters), over 0.1-10s measurement period.

Capacitor would be somewhere in 5-100pF range.

I guess, charging it through some large resistor, and measuring voltage via 24-bit ADC would not cut it.

Is that possible to make LC-generator somewhere at 10-100Mhz range, and then directly count each oscilation => calculate capacitance?

Or probably there are some better ways for precise capacitance measurement?

**Update:** 9 digits means that I need to see difference between 50.000000 and 50.0000001 pF. Knowing absolute value (50.0000001 pF) is not important, I just need to see that capacitance increased or decreased by .0000001 pF (or .0000237 pF, etc)

Comment: Why this accuracy? Measuring anything to a precision better than 0.5% is usually a challenge.

Comment: I think you'll find that your requirements are unrealistic; even 14-bit ADC design work is a challenge if you want more than noise in the LSB. And oscillator design means your other components in the oscillator must be at least as accurate.  I think a better question to ask is why you feel you need that much precision, and if there isn't a better way to achieve what you're really after.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Are capacitor values even stable enough for this to make sense?

Comment: @starblue - No, they're not, and I can't think of *any* application where it matters either.

Comment: @starblue - Capacitor instability is exactly what I need to monitor using this, I want to use capacitance change to measure physical parameters change.

Comment: @barsmonster - I would maybe start by examining at the physics behind this, and build up a mathematical model to see where things get "fuzzy".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know there is a DIY uC design that does it both ways you suggest above:

[Elmcie LC meter](http://www.aplomb.nl/TechStuff/Elmcie/Elmcie.html)

it has the unknown C (or L) as part of an oscillator for the smaller range, and for larger capacitance it charges with constant current and measures time.

However the pro meters usually (I think from what I have seen/heard/read) use a different technique - roughly, they put a very clean accurate sine through the unknown as part of a LC filter and then measure the phase change. I had a great paper on the design of of one of these that involved an FPGA, but I can't seem to find it.. If I do manage to I'll add it afterwards.

Anyway I think for small pF measurements the oscillator method should achieve around/under 1pF resolution, and will be the easiest to make yourself.

Note, there is a boring option, which is buy a dedicated IC, a few available and found on Digikey, Farnell etc. Add multidigit display (should have BCD output) and you're done. I think many(most?) multimeters use them.

EDIT - *I think* relative accuracy of 8-9 digits will be pretty much impossible to achieve. Even the most advanced LCR meters from e.g. Agilent [E49840A](http://www.home.agilent.com/agilent/product.jspx?nid=-34124.536908436.00&cc=GB&lc=eng) (~£10k to buy) will "only" achieve measurements of around a femtoFarad maybe 100aF, and from what I can see relative accuracy is in parts per million. I wouldn't like to try and calibrate one of those things :-)

I think trying to make one of these would probably be nearly as involved as making say, a [Lecroy Wavemaster](http://www.lecroy.com/oscilloscope/oscilloscopeseries.aspx?mseries=329) scope. A *lot* of money, people, and research needed. Maybe you could talk to some test equipment experts and see what they think is possible though.

Comment: 9 digits means that I need to see difference between 50.000000 and 50.0000001 pF. I doubt off-the-shelf ICs can offer such capability.

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt anything can.. :-)

Comment: Here is an off-the-shelf chip designed for capacitance measurement: http://www.acam-usa.com/Capacitance-Circuits.html  It is a dual-slope converter and advertises 22 bits of resolution.

Comment: Interesting, that looks pretty good - 22bit (1/4000000) resolution and range down to a few fF according to specs.

Comment: @markrages - that 6 1/2 digits of *resolution*, which is a far cry from 6 1/2 digits of *precision*, let alone 9 digits. My 10 euro fever thermometer has 4 significant digits of resolution, but probably less than 3 digits of precision.

Comment: @stevenvh - The ENOB seems to range from ~21 - 14 from what I can make out whilst skimming the literature. Here is a table: http://www.acam-usa.com/Cap-Ps021-Resolution.html

Comment: @stevenvh Good point. ACAM's resolution far exceeds precision in my experience.

Comment: @Oli, ACAM literature is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Forget it! :-)

Typically you'd measure capacitance by measuring the rate of change of the voltage over it during charging or decharging. 9 significant digits mean that your least significant digit (LSD) is 1nV(!) for 1V full scale. It's not impossible to get this kind of resolution, even 15 digits are possible if you want. The thing is that most of your "significant digits" aren't significant at all. They're just noise, you could use them as a random number generator. Just looking at your setup already changes the readout.

> *What's the use of having 9 digits if you can't get the 4 LSDs to display a stable value?*

Most every day engineering calculations can be done with 3 significant digits. For complex chains of calculations you may occasionally need 4 or 5 digits in intermediate results, but most likely the result will be 1.23V, not 1.234715V.

> *A 1mm\$^2\$ parallel plate capacitor with 0.01mm separation gives about 1pF. To have a change of one 9th digit of this value (1 zeptoFarad) you'd have to displace the plates 10fm (femtometer). Success!*

Comment: In my case I unfortunately indeed need 8-9 stable digits, that's for physical measurements through capacitance.

Comment: @Barsmonster - I can understand that you want/need it, but it's *very hard* to get real significant readings that way. For instance a tenth of a degree change in temperature may cause a big change.

Comment: not to mention the vibration of people walking across the floor, movement of the wires, hell I bet random radioactive decay would cause the measurement to change.  This is not a reasonable request.

Comment: LIGO can measure 0.001 femtometers.  It will only cost you $370 million.

Comment: @endolith - Dammit, that LIGO is $370 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 per meter! ;-)

Comment: @stevenvh I understand that this all should be temperature-stabilized :-)

Comment: @BarsMonster: everything-stabilized! 9 digits should give you a different C for a different voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitors vary with temperature and a variety of other factors.  Is there any way that one can either regulate the temperature of a cap so perfectly that it drifts less than one part per billion, or can measure the temperature sufficiently accurately to provide compensation that's meaningful to that level of precision?  Also, by what exact definition are you seeking to measure capacitance?  A typical cap will behave as a combination of many smaller caps interconnected with various resistances, inductances, and non-linear elements.  The number of electrons required to cause a one-volt potential change on a good cap will be constant within a small fraction, but not even the best caps will get the variance into the parts-per-billion range (one some caps, the variance may be more like one part in four).

Comment: As I was mentioning, this is for measuring physical changes by observing capacitance change. So, I DO expect that capacitance would change, this is desired effect. I only need to know what is capacitance delta.

Comment: The phenomenon you're interested in may be changing the capacitance, but will it be the *only* thing that changes the capacitance?  I would expect that there are probably other factors which will change the capacitance by a lot more than a few parts per billion.

Comment: I guess I will have to try to isolate other things which might affect that, most notably temperature change.

Answer (score 0):

9 digits is 1 ppm! But you ask only for a relative (delta) reading, which is a lot easier than an absolute reading. A standard crystal is 50 ppm accurate, I guess a crystal oscillator in a small temperature-controlled oven can easily be 1 ppm stable over 10 seconds. If you can put your capacitor as frequency-determining element in an oscillator you can use a microcontroller (with the stabilised xtal as clock) to measure the frequency. Most uC's have an external counter input that can handle a few MHz, so you need less than a second of measuring time to get a one-tick difference that corresponds to 1 ppm. Except for the oscillator with your capacitor (I am no expert in that field) in it I think this is all doable.

Another approach would be mix the output of the your-capacitor-socillator with the reference oscillator, and analyse the difference signal in the mix. Percentwise it will vary much more than your capacitor.

But as others have said, do you realise how much influence environmental factors that you probably do not control will have on your capacitor? Think of temperature, air pressure, vibrations, magnetic field variations, natural radioactivity, maybe even brownian motion of air molecules.

Comment: No, 9 digits is 1 part per billion.  6 digits would be 1 ppm.

Comment: Drat, that makes the 'count the cycles' approach unrealistic.

Comment: There is no life beyond few ppm on the way to ppb. But the attempts for higher resolution are always entertaining